# Breadcrumbs in dynamics 365

Tags: dynamics-crm, breadcrumbs, dynamics-365, powerapps-modeldriven

I have a model driven app, in which I need to add breadcrumbs or navigation to show the user's location, as shown below
Eg: Assignment/Sub-Assignment/Project

Is there any in built functionality or how can I implement it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately the breadcrumb navigation is removed by Microsoft in latest release. It’s not supported to customize it anyway.

> The header breadcrumb has been removed to align with Office header styling and to make space for the upcoming app search box in the header. To support this navigation change and help users with navigation discovery, page back buttons have been added to the main page types of Form, View, and Dashboard.

[Reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-platform-release-plan/2020wave2/power-apps/improved-model-driven-app-header-sitemap-app-switching?WT.mc_id=DX-MVP-5004422#feature-details)